# Exact values from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist that contains arraylists. If I would like to `get` first element I get similar to the following output:

```
[26,287 154,303 375,338 260,393]
```

What should I do to get exactly element 375? How can I refer to a specified element from this output?

Comment: Are you looking for `arrayList.get(4);`? Also check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html?is-external=true

Comment: You should study the Java doc for java.util.ArrayList; alternatively, you might consider studying the excellent tutorial from Oracle regarding collections ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/ )

Comment: Use `arrayList.get(1).get(4)` (returns 375)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have the following variable declaration

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists;
```

With a

```
listOfLists.get(0)
```

you get the first element of that list which is a list itself. Outputting it will result in what you described.

You now must simply *get* the wanted element from that list:

```
System.out.println(listOfLists.get(0).get(4));
```

This will simply output

> 375

Answer (score 0):

you have an arraylist that contains arraylists, you mean to say a list of lists.

looking at the output it seems this is a list of Strings.

you can take individual elements of the list in an array and then split the array based on ','. this will give you 303 375 in the third cell, you again need to split it and get your desired result

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
 arrayList.get(0).get(0);
```

This will do your job. You have 2 lists, so you need to take list witch contains integers and then take the value.